# Error with overleaf (no PDF)

Tags: errors, overleaf, compilation-error, overleaf-toolkit

I have a fairly serious issue on my document. I get the following error:

```
    This compile didn’t produce a PDF. This can happen if:
There is an unrecoverable LaTeX error. If there are LaTeX errors shown below or in the raw logs, please try to fix them and compile again.
The document environment contains no content. If it’s empty, please add some content and compile again.
This project contains a file called output.pdf. If that file exists, please rename it and compile again.
```

However, when I download a previous version as a zip file and try to upload it back to overleaf, it says that the file is too big to upload!

I have tried copying over the individual sections to a new project from the last working version, but to no avail (I still get the error).

Have you encountered this before? Any ideas on how to fix it please?

The first known error that is in the log is:

```
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.2741 ...yHist\\}}\relax }{figure.caption.725}{}}
                                                  
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
```

Comment: that just  means there was an error. The log file should show what the error was.

Comment: We've all encountered errors, for many different reasons.  That makes it very difficult to diagnose an error without more information.  Overleaf probably shows you some other error as well; can you paste that here?  If you copy individual sections to a new project and still have the error, then you can start narrowing down your search for what in your code is causing the error.

Comment: `This project contains a file called output.pdf` have you uploaded the pdf as a source file in your project?

Comment: ask the overleaf support for help.

Comment: The error on line 2741 is unfortunately caused by some other error.  You'll need to do a bit more debugging.

Comment: you have presumably used a fragile command in a figure caption but you have not given enough information to allow anyone to help.   You can presumably recognise the text fragment `yHist\\ ` related to figure.caption.725  (a `\\ ` at the end of an argument looks _very_ odd, what is your full latex source for that caption?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hi, the code for that section is: \chapter{Axiovision Greyscale Histograms}
\label{sec:greyHistograms}
\raggedbottom
\foreach \x[count=\z] in \histogramImages
{
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[max size={\textwidth}{\textheight}]{figures/Histograms/\x.png}
        \caption{Greyscale Histogram for \x{\label{fig:greyHist\z}}}
    \end{figure}
}

Comment: how come `\z` is appearing as `\\ ` in the error?? start by commenting out that `\label` and  see if tex gets unstuck. You can make a small example with just that construction and ask here if you need it (but 999 times out of 1000 you do not need auto-generated labels)

Comment: Hi, @DavidCarlisle I tried deleting the sections that autogenerate labels and the same error persists! I'm not sure why its still trying to read code that I've deleted...

Comment: the error is in the aux file so as well as fixing the source you may need to delete the aux file (`clear cached files` button in overleaf's "logs" view)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that did the trick! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is a malformed caption in the aux file for table of contents.

You can see this from the error fragment shown in comments under the question

```
l.2741 ...yHist\\}}\relax }{figure.caption.725}{}}
```

So line 2741 of some file, you may recognise the syntax to determine which file, or the full log would show the file name, work up the log to the first `(` with no matching `)` which is probably

```
(./output.aux
```

showing `output.aux` is being read at that point.

The error context is

```
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.2741 ...yHist\\}}\relax }{figure.caption.725}{}}
                                                  
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
```

From which you recognised the original source as

```
\foreach \x[count=\z] in \histogramImages {
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[max size={\textwidth}{\textheight}]{figures/Histograms/\x.png}
\caption{Greyscale Histogram for \x{\label{fig:greyHist\z}}}
\end{figure}
}
```

`\label{fig:greyHist\z}` looks suspicious and can be removed.
As the corrupted file are read in at the start of each run, you want to delete them so clean ones get written. On overleaf that is:

[image]

You probably don't need the labels, but if you do, they could be put back but the details would depend on code not shown.